# Java split (String Manipulation)

Tags: java, string, split

I want to display the data from an EMAIL_TEXT database column splitting the columns at a defined character. For some reason my results are only printing the first line up to where I split the string skipping the rest of the lines.  Here is the data I wish to split after every "|".

Here is a sample of the database column to be split.

```
TEXT TEXT Line1 |

TEXT TEXT Line2 |
```

The results printed are:

```
TEXT TEXT Line1
```

The desired results are :

```
TEXT TEXT Line1  
TEXT TEXT Line2
```

Here is my Java Code:

```
String[] result = EMAIL_TEXT.split("\\|");
String subject="";
BufferedReader br;
BufferedReader brCSS;
FileReader fr;
FileReader frCSS;
String content="";
String CssContent="";
Document document1=null;
String FILEPATH = get(Fields.In, "FILEPATH").getString(r);

String filePathArray []=FILEPATH.split(",");
String mainContents = "";
int j;
try{
    for(j=0;j<filePathArray.length;j++)
    {
        subject= get(Fields.In,"EMAIL_SUBJECT").getString(r);

        fr=new FileReader(filePathArray[j]);
        br= new BufferedReader(fr);
        String s;
        content = "";
        String c;
        if(mainContents.contains("header-image.jpeg")!=true)
        {
            mainContents += "<img src=header-image.jpeg>";
        }
        content = content + result[j];
        while(( s=br.readLine())!=null)
        {

            content=content+s;

        }


    }
```

Comment: Can you take a sysout of EMAIL_TEXT and post it here

Comment: Honestly I don't think the rest of the code is relevant other than the EMAIL_TEXT.split();

Comment: Is `filePathArray` the same length as `result`? You are using the same index `j` in both `filePathArray[j]` and `result[j]`.

Comment: No they are of different lengths with the result being a much longer string.

Comment: You most likely want to use nested `for`-loops then. One loop for `result`, and one for `filePathArray`.
But it's hard to tell, when I don't know how you want to put together the text from the arrays and files.

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] result = EMAIL_TEXT.split("\\|");
for(String s:result){
   System.out.println(s);
}
```

you have all the text inside result array... just loop through them  to get all of the lines...